# How to make slider cards smaller and bringing them together without having empty spaces or overflow in using swiper js plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, e-commerce, swiper.js

Using html, css, js to create a responsive card slider with swiper js plugin, i made each card smaller e.g 40% and use e.g -20vw to display like 2 cards on the screen on each time i slide, and when i do that, on scrolling to the right i end up seeing spaces or rather, overflow instead of seeing the end.

I used ChatGPT to find solution and i realized it was the -20vw margin that was the cause... But the thing is, I WANT THE CARDS TO BE CLOSE, NOT ONE CARD ON THE SCREEN EACH TIME I SLIDE.. I’M WORKING ON AN E-COMMERCE SITE.

TAKE A LOOK AT JUMIA.NG FOR EXAMPLE

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the swiperjs (swiperjs.com) plugin and you want to have more than one slide in view each time, then you need to initialize the slider with the `slidesPerView` parameter. See: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-slidesPerView.

Example:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  ...,
  slidesPerView : 2,
  ...
});
```

If you need to have different number of slides per view, per breakpoint, then you can use the breakpoints parameter. You can read more about that here: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-breakpoints.

If you need to control the width of the slider then you should set the width parameter.

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  ...,
  width: 600,
  ...
});
```